# XCode--When do I sign with developer provisioning profile vs distribution profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to prepare my app in Xcode 4.6 for enterprise deployment.  I am getting this error:  "failed to get the task for process 5057".

Under the project's build settings' Code signing identity section, I have selected the iPhone Distribution provisioning profile that I made for my app (it is valid).  I did not select the development provisioning profile as my identity, b/c I'm trying enterprise distribution.

But of course, I get the error "failed to get task for process 5057".  Why am I getting this error?  I know that the fix is to use the development provisioning profile, but why--I want to prepare my app for distribution.

Should I have two schemes for my app, one for development and one for release?  And inside the dev scheme, I use my dev provisioning profile and inside my release build settings, I use my distribution provisioning profile?

XCode has made this very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Failed to get task sounds like you're trying to run this build via Xcode on device. If that's the case, you want to use a development profile, not a distribution profile (AdHoc). If you're attempting to create an enterprise release build, you'll want to select your target and choose the iOS device option, then use Product > Archive to create a release build.

Comment: Thanks.  So are my code signing identities always my development provisioning profile?  Shouldn't I sign with my company's provisioning profile identity for an enterprise release?  I don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: There are different profiles for different types of builds. Development profiles are used for developing on device, but are not meant to be used for distribution to other devices. AdHoc profiles are meant to be used for releases to enterprise users or other users (say, for testing or enterprise distribution) and App Store profiles are meant to be used for App Store distribution. The second two (AdHoc and App Store) are distribution profiles, the first (Dev) is a development profile.

Comment: You want to create a development profile and set your development scheme to use that when developing on device, and you want to create an AdHoc profile and set your AdHoc scheme to use that so you can create distributions.

Comment: See this for more: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html

Comment: OK, I have a release scheme and a debug scheme for my app.  For my debug scheme, my code signing identity is "iPhone Developer".  For my release scheme, do I change my code signing identity to "iPhone distribution"? I have a release scheme and a dev scheme b/c in dev, all my URLs point to a dev server, and in release, all my URLs point to a production server.

Comment: Yes, you can set your release scheme to use your distribution profile.